# MS Excel - replicating a series of cells

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have the following data in a spreadsheet:

I [image]

I need a formula/workaround that would give me the following:

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference and repeat data by using the `INDEX` function.

Placing the formula `=INDEX(A:A,FLOOR((ROW()+4)/5,1),1)` into a cell on the first row (`B1`, `C1`, etc.) and copying down will repeat everything in column A 5 times.